# What is the best way to add a custom compile-time processing step to Java?

Tags: java

What is the simplest way to add a compile-time step to analyse and modify the source code before it is compiled to byte code?

Can I write this in Java?
Would it be best written as an IDE plugin?

Comment: what do you mean by `modify the source code` ?

Comment: I am thinking `Bytecode Manipulation`.

Comment: For example, analysing parts of the code and splitting the work into multiple threads where necessary

Comment: you mean preprocessing java code with your own api?

Comment: Yes - although I haven't done this before I assumed it would be easier to do this before it is byte code?

Comment: Maybe you could do it as part of an ant build script?

Comment: Might be a case for Maven. You could even write your own Maven plugin which performs your analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I write this in Java?

Yes, definitely.  There are numerous Java based libraries for manipulating bytecode:

- [Commons BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/)
- [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)
- [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

> Would it be best written as an IDE plugin?

In my opinion, no.  You didn't mention which IDE you're using, but from my own experience, writing an IDE plugin has a steeper learning curve than adding a custom step to a build tool like Ant/Maven/Gradle.  Even if you aren't currently using one of these build tools, in my personal opinion, it would be easier to adopt one of these tools rather than write an IDE plugin.

Also, tying a build step to a particular IDE makes your build less portable.  Two things to consider before going this route:

1) How you would run your build on a continuous integration server like Jenkins or Bamboo.  It's not impossible to invoke a headless Eclipse/Netbeans build that uses custom plugins on a build server, but it's not nearly as straightforward as running a build that uses "standard" tools like Ant/Maven/Gradle.

2) How would it impact other members of your team?  You'd need to find a way to distribute to the plugin to each developer, deal with versioning and updates of the plugin, etc.  Is everyone on your team using the same IDE?

I don't know anything about your project, your team (if you're working on a team), or the type of software you're developing so these considerations may not apply to you.  I've only mentioned them as food for thought based on my own experiences.

> What is the simplest way to add a compile-time step to analyse and
>   modify the source code before it is compiled to byte code?

What are you using for your builds?  Ant? Maven? Gradle?  The exact steps you'd follow are highly dependent on your build tool.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may not need to write anything at all.

> For example, analysing parts of the code and splitting the work into
>   multiple threads where necessary –

Check out [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/).  You can probably write an aspect that intercepts calls to certain methods and submits them to an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  There are off the shelf plugins to invoke the AspectJ compiler from most common build systems.

If you do want to write something on your own, I think your best bet would be to [write a custom Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html).  I suggest an Ant task because it's the lowest common denominator.  It can of course be run using Ant, but both Maven and Gradle can invoke Ant tasks as well.

Write a new class that [extends Task](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.7.0/org/apache/tools/ant/Task.html) and do your thing in there.

```
public class MyTask extends Task {
    public void execute() {
     // do your bytecode manipulation here...
    }
}
```

You'd invoke it like this from your Ant script:

```
<taskdef name="mytask" classname="MyTask" classpath="classes"/>
<mytask/>
```

Check out the [Apache Axis2 code generation task](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.axis2/axis2-ant-plugin/1.5.3/org/apache/axis2/tool/ant/AntCodegenTask.java) for an example of doing build time code generation and how to deal with classpath issues/accessing your code.